# how could I integrate a signature into an X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have been trying for a couple of days now to find out how to integrate a signature into an X509Certificate but I am stacked.

> since X509Certificate itself has no such a function, I have not found an alternative way to do it. is this possible? if yes how could I do it.

Comment: just guessing here but have you looked at java.security.Signature class?

Comment: ciny.. I am not sure whether I understand what you mean but I already have the signature and want to integrate it into the certificate.

Comment: You need to introduce custom extension (with your own OID) and place the data there. Still it will be only your software that will recognize such extension.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp does this mean that there is no way arround to do it without going out of the normal standard. because I want my certificate to be recognized by standard tools

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood you. What kind of signature do you want to incorporate? Is it the signature made by the CA? If yes, then I don't know if it's possible with BouncyCastle, though in general it is possible of course (eg. using our SecureBlackbox). And if you mean some handmade signature (a picture), then you put it as a custom extension, but the certificate itself remains usable.

Comment: yes I actually making some kind of CA. but due to the signing process I need to make some handmade signature then incorporate it in certificate which could be verifiable by standard tools

Comment: The extension becomes signed with the rest of the certificate and as such it is verified during certificate validation process. Yet there seems to be no standard extension for user's handmade signature that other software would recognize. If you come across one, please let everybody know.

Comment: at the moment I haven't found anything. in case I get something useful I make it public